# Attributes as function arguments

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, attributes

I have defined a class named `Score`

```
class Score():
    
    def __init__(self, player, dealer):
        
        self.player = player
        self.dealer = dealer

score = Score(31,27)
```

After this I defined a function named `change_score` which performs arithmetic operation on the value of attributes of the score object.

```
def change_score(i, attribute):
    
    if i > 0:
        score.attribute += 4
    else:
        score.attribute -= 1

    return score.attribute
```

However when i pass an attribute like this:

```
change_score(0, player)
```

The following error pops up: **NameError: name 'player' is not defined**

How should i do it then?

Answer (score 0):

A better method going about this would be to add the function to the class so that it makes it easier to manage, and you also need to define the attribute in the **init**() method making it and instance attribute

So the new code would be:

```
class Score:

    def __init__(self, player, dealer): # add an the attribute here if you want

        self.player = player
        self.dealer = dealer
        self.attribute = 0 # Then set that attribute parameter here (if you want)

    def change_score(self, i):
        if i > 0:
            self.attribute += 4
        else:
            self.attribute -= 1
        return self.attribute
```

Outside of the Class add:

```
score = Score(31, 27)
score.change_score(-1)
```